# Don't display labels in subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the following subplot, I want to have labels displayed in the legend; therefore, I need to have labels set, but I don't want them to be displayed. That is, I want the legend only, I don't want label names next to my pie-charts. How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
my_labels = ['food', 'music', 'clothes']

fig = pylab.figure()
fig.text(0.4,0.95,"Consumption by Region")

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
ax1.pie([1,2,3], labels = my_labels)
ax1.text(0.6, 1, "North West")

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)
ax2.pie([6,4,3], labels = my_labels)
ax2.text(0.6, 1, "North East")

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,3)
ax3.pie([1,4,3], labels = my_labels)
ax3.text(0.6, 1, "South West")

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,4)
ax4.pie([9,1,3], labels = my_labels)
ax4.text(0.6, 1, "South East")

pylab.legend(title="Legend", loc=(-1.5,0.9))

pylab.show()
```

Which produces:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want them in at the individual pie chart, the labels should not be called at the plotting but only when defining the legend:

```
import pylab

my_labels = ['food', 'music', 'clothes']

fig = pylab.figure()
fig.text(0.4,0.95,"Consumption by Region")

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
ax1.pie([1,2,3])
ax1.text(0.6, 1, "North West")

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)
ax2.pie([6,4,3])
ax2.text(0.6, 1, "North East")

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,3)
ax3.pie([1,4,3])
ax3.text(0.6, 1, "South West")

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,4)
ax4.pie([9,1,3])
ax4.text(0.6, 1, "South East")

pylab.legend(my_labels, title="Legend", loc=(-1.5,0.9))

pylab.show()
```

This results in:

[image]